# Tomcat port 8080 to 80

Tags: apache, tomcat

I installed Apache2 and Tomcat7 on Ubuntu14

```
http://mysite.it/                    -> Apache OK
http://mysite.it/phpmyadmin          -> Apache OK, showing phpmyadmin
http://mysite.it:8080/myApp/         -> Tomcat OK, showing my Spring App
```

The 8080 port is closed in the Client intranet, and **he would like to use http://mysite.it/myApp/**.
I need to setup the proxy/reverse proxy in Apache2

Here there is what I did:

```
aptitude    update
aptitude -y upgrade
aptitude install -y build-essential
aptitude install -y libapache2-mod-proxy-html libxml2-dev    
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
a2enmod proxy_ajp
a2enmod rewrite
a2enmod deflate
a2enmod headers
a2enmod proxy_balancer
a2enmod proxy_connect
a2enmod proxy_html
a2enmod xml2enc
```

Now I should modify /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

The current (default) version is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

---

I tried to add also this snippet, but no luck

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass /myApp/ http://mysite.it:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse /myApp/ http://mysite.it:8080/

    ServerName mysite.it
</VirtualHost>
```

Can anyone help me?
Riccardo

***** SOLUTION ******
Just one virtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass /myApp/ http://mysite.it:8080/myApp/
    ProxyPassReverse /myApp/ http://mysite.it:8080/myApp/

    ServerName mysite.it

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Did you try to put `http://mysite.it:8080/myApp/` in the proxyreverse instead of only `http://mysite.it:8080/`? Also I dont know if you already know this... but it is necessary to restart the apache when you chacne the config

Comment: Hello, yes I know that I need to "service apache2 restart"

Comment: Don't know if this VirtualHost is conflictig with the default one. Should I delete the first VirtualHost?

Comment: The next step is to look into the error and access logs to see if anything obvious is wrong.

Comment: I think the two `VirtualHost` entries conflict with each other. You need to merge them or you need to set different `ServerName`s. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: get "Error 404: The requested URL /tlt/ was not found on this server."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the context name (myApp) at the end the ProxyPass target:

```
ProxyPass /myApp/ http://mysite.it:8080/myApp/
ProxyPassReverse /myApp/ http://mysite.it:8080/myApp/
```

instead of

```
ProxyPass /myApp/ http://mysite.it:8080/
ProxyPassReverse /myApp/ http://mysite.it:8080/
```

Comment: Thanks, I also merged both VirtualHost, to just one with <VirtualHost *:*>. Is it right?

Comment: Not sure if it makes any difference to merge the virtual hosts, but that's something to try. Is it working?

Comment: If I use two virtualHosts, it does not work... (see the UPDATE). However you got the point! Thanks